# Failing to Model-Bind posted form values to my custom .net type (cart) which is stored in session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

When the form in the below view is submitted the cart object
in session fails to update with the client side inputed values.
Am I missing something ? Is the custom model binder to blame ?

All the element names are 1:1 with the cart object property names and structure.

**View Excerpt:**

```
         <% using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateCart", "Cart"))
       { %>



<% int index = 0; %>

<% foreach (var line in Model.Cart.Lines)
   { %>
<tr>
<%: Html.Hidden("Lines.Index", index) %>
<td align="center"><%: Html.TextBox("Lines[" + index + "].Quantity", line.Quantity)%></td>
<td align="left"><%: line.Product.Name%></td>
<td align="right"><%: line.Product.ListPrice.ToString("c")%></td>
<td align="right">
<%: (line.Quantity * line.Product.ListPrice).ToString("c")%>
</td>
</tr>

<%--<%: Html.Hidden("Lines[" + index + "].Product.ProductID", line.Product.ProductID)%>--%>

<% index++; %>

<% } %>

    <%: Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Model.ReturnUrl) %>


    <input type="submit" value="Update Cart" />

    <% } %>
```

**Cart Object:**

```
    public class Cart
{
  private IList<CartLine> lines = new List<CartLine>();
    public IList<CartLine> Lines { get { return lines; } set { lines = value; } }
}

    public class CartLine
    {
        public Product Product
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public int Quantity
        { get; set; }
    }
```

**Action Method that receives posted form data and should update the cart object by binding the form values:**

```
[HttpPost]
    public RedirectToRouteResult UpdateCart(Cart cart, string returnUrl)
    {



         return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });

    }
```

**Custom model binder that instantiates cart in session and returns that instance for all controllers and methods to use.**

```
public class CartModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{



    private const string cartSessionKey = "_cart";

    protected override void OnModelUpdated(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        controllerContext.HttpContext.Session[cartSessionKey] = (Cart)bindingContext.Model;
    }




        public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            //if (bindingContext.Model != null)
            //    throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot update instances");

            Cart cart = (Cart)controllerContext.HttpContext.Session[cartSessionKey];

            if (cart == null)
            {
                cart = new Cart();
                controllerContext.HttpContext.Session[cartSessionKey] = cart;

            }

            return cart;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you register your model binder for Card type? BTW, are you reading Steven Sanderson's book? Good choice

Comment: Yes, it's registered "ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(Cart), new CartModelBinder());" in the global file. And yes, that's the book I am using and from what I have seen it's the best one so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cutom modelbinder you created is called when you post your data to ther server, so your parameter cart of the action UpdateCart will be loaded with the data from client using the modelbinder. To use a custom modelbinder to update your session after the object is loaded you can do this:

```
public class CartModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    private const string cartSessionKey = "_cart";

    protected override void OnModelUpdated(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        controllerContext.HttpContext.Session[cartSessionKey] = bindingContext.Model;
    }
}
```

In this modelbinder we are inheriting the defaultmodelbinder and overiding the OnModelUpdate event that happens after the model is binded, so in the OnModelUpdated we have the model with the values from the view and we can set the session.

But for the DefaultModelBinder do the bind you'll have to change you view, the names of the inputs must match the names of the properties of your object, so instead of cart.Lines[" + index + "].Quantity you should use Lines[" + index + "].Quantity (do the same for the other properties). In you Cart object you'll have to create a setter for the Lines property because without that the defaultbinder won't be able to set the value inputed. You don't need to call UpdateModel inside your view.

Comment: You are saying that when I post to the server CartModelBinder is used to provide the cart object and populate it with the posted values from the view and pass the populated object to the parameter in the  UpdateCart action method. However to update the cart object in my session I need to add the above code with the OnModelUpdadated override and make CartModelBinder inherit from DefaultModelBinder ?  Why change the element names in view to "Lines["+ index +"]" and not "cart.Lines["+ index +"]" afterall I am dealing with the cart object ? Can u give example of how CartModelBinder should look?

Comment: You should change the names because the DefaultModelBinder of ASPNET MVC will try to bind the parameters posted by the client based on the properties names. So if you have an object with a property called Lines (like your Cart) you have to use this name on your input on the view, you don't have to use the word cart because it's not a porperty of Cart object. But for that to work your Cart object must have a setter for Lines. The final CartModelBinder is in my answer.

Comment: I have now updated the CartModelBinder to what I currently have, see original question above. How should I properly implement the setter on the public IList<CartLine> Lines { get { return lines.AsReadOnly(); } } , IList is an interface and the usual  set { lines = value; } does not appear to work. Thanks..

Comment: You can change your class variable to private IList<CartLine> lines, this way you can implement the setter with lines = value.

Comment: I now have: private IList<CartLine> lines = new List<CartLine>();
public IList<CartLine> Lines { get { return lines; } set { lines = value; } } But the damn thing still won't bind. My CartModelBinder is it looking ok ?

Comment: You don't have to override the BindModel, let the default BindModel method do the magic.

Comment: If I don't override the CartModelBinder.BindModel it states that it hides the inherited member DefaultModelBinder.BindModel stating I should either override or add the  new keyword. If I don't override BindModel then the cart object fails to instantiate in session and I can't add anything to the cart at all, let alone update quantity which is what I am trying to do now. If I don't implement BindModel at all same thing.

Comment: I managed to get it working, just had to save and get the cart from session manually with some code in index and AddToCart acttion methods instead of having it passed in as a parameter. However for UpdateCart it's passed in as a parameter and binds fine. The only issue I am having is that ideally I would want to update the existing cart in session and not overwrite it with the one created in bindingContext.Model from the posted values. This way I can just pass quantity value and not Product Name, Price etc.